# Need to assign specific IP Address for domains outbound IPV4 in Smartermail

Tags: server, mail-server

I am running on windows server 2008 with Smartermail installed as a mail service. I have 2 domain hosted on the Smartermail. For both the domains i have to assign specific IPV4 outbound ip address. It mens if anyone domain's ip address blacklisted due to any reason the other domain will remain intake. Mails can be send from the another domain in case of other got blacklisted.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

Herrick,

Yes, SmarterMail provides feature to set outbound IP Address for a domain. For that, you must have an access to SmarterMail admin panel. If so, then perform following steps:

-> Login into SmarterMail admin panel.
-> Search your domain in domains section for which you want to set outbound IP Address.
-> Right click on that domain and click on edit.
-> Go to Technical Features tab.

From there you can set outbound IP Address for a domain. Hope, this will help you to set your requirement.

Regards,